# BottomNavigationBar set up But No Change of State

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

Using the code below I set up a BottomNavigationBar widget for testing in Flutter.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Thursday20 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Thursday20({super.key});

  @override
  State<Thursday20> createState() => _Thursday20State();
}

class _Thursday20State extends State<Thursday20> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int _selectedIndex = 0;

    void _zzzxx(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }

    final screens = [
      Center(child: Text('HHHHH', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
      Center(child: Text('SSSSS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
      Center(child: Text('EEEEE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
      Center(child: Text('PPPPP', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
          iconSize: 37.0,
          selectedFontSize: 16.0,
          unselectedFontSize: 11.0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.label_important),
              label: 'Forwards',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.wallet),
              label: 'Wallet',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.backspace_outlined),
              label: 'Delete',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map_outlined),
              label: 'Zoom Out',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Following the examples from a video tutorial, I expected the text on the screen to change with each selection of the navigation-bar-options, but instead the screen remains still as a constant in the way it loaded, despite selections.

Is there something that I have done wrong and could you direct me in the direction of my expected outcome please?

With thanks.

Comment: I understand you on that, but when calling that method didn't work I rewrote the setState call at the onTap function to do exactly as seen in the video.  And still it didn't work.  Do you also mean that the onTap function entered is incorrect please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selectedIndex` is part of your `build` method. It should instead be part of your state.

Your build method is executed every time you call `setState`, and since `selectedIndex` is declared inside, it is always initialized with a value of 0.

Solution: Make `selectedIndex` part of your state class.

```
class _Thursday20State extends State<Thursday20> {
  /// [selectedIndex] is now part of your state.
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// remove [selectedIndex] from here.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  The problem was as you explained.  Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

You have declared and defined your selected index variable to be 0 inside the build method. Your build method is called every time you rebuild the screen causing the selected index to stay at 0 instead of getting updated. To resolve this issue, you can simply move it outside your build method and preferably place it inside your _Thursday20State class. Here's a modification of your code snippet.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Thursday20 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Thursday20({super.key});

  @override
  State<Thursday20> createState() => _Thursday20State();
}

class _Thursday20State extends State<Thursday20> {
int _selectedIndex = 0; // I have brought this line here and have also removed 
// the zzzxx method. 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screens = [
      Center(child: Text('HHHHH', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
      Center(child: Text('SSSSS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
      Center(child: Text('EEEEE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
      Center(child: Text('PPPPP', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),),),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
          iconSize: 37.0,
          selectedFontSize: 16.0,
          unselectedFontSize: 11.0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.label_important),
              label: 'Forwards',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.wallet),
              label: 'Wallet',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.backspace_outlined),
              label: 'Delete',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map_outlined),
              label: 'Zoom Out',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for your response Naqeeb : )